# Preventing Ajax save data two times

Tags: ajax, mobile, double, call

Whenever I run Ajax in jquery, it will run two times. It will cause a problem in saving data. I googled and used their metods but none of them worked. The following is the ways I tried:

1. Set a global flag. Set it on when Ajax is running, turn it off after done. It seems that duplicated calls manage the flag concurrently. Before call 1 closed the door, call 2 is already in in no time. Or check time if less than 4000, do not run Ajax.
2. Generating a random number and attach to the url, they are the same always.
3. event.preventPropgador();e.preventDefault();  does not work in whichever order
4. async:true or false  does not work
5. I cannot use "once" since I am usimg jQuery Mobile

   $("#submitButton").once("tap", function () { //<-- error
               save();
    });
6. used "one" but not work

   $("#submitButton").one("tap", function () { 
               save();
    });
7. disable the button when ajax running, then enable it afterwords.

I tried above techs on save() and Ajax calls, none of them worked.
This is my code like:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
            $("#submitButton").one("tap", function () {
                save();
            });
}

function save() {  
    $.ajax({method: "get",
                    url: baseUrl + "save?model=abcd&rand=" + randonNum(),                    
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                         //do whatever
                    }
            },
           error: function (request, status, error, errorThrown) {

           }
         });
}
```

Comment: I added the Ajax call in a function. In Chrome console, I call this function, the Ajax is called two times when I check with Fiddler.

Comment: function getSummary(){
             $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: baseUrl + "daily?rand=" + randigit(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#s1").html( response.dailyScraps);                    
                },
                error: function (request, status, error, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
}